# How to merge two array object element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, merge

input :

```
var b= [{
    "cat_id": "1",
    "cat_name": "teaching"
  }];

  var a= [  {
    "username": "r",
    "password": "r"
  }];
```

I want output like this

```
[{"username":"r","password":"r","cat_id":"1","cat_name":"teaching"}]
```

Comment: `var result = Object.assign({}, b[0], a[0])`

Comment: add jquery https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js and apply this

 $.extend( a[0], b[0] );

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest This may not work if his array has multiple object as you have hard coded 0 here

Comment: No way to merge directly. You have to iterate the array list and merge it manually

Comment: @madhairsilence, he doesn't mention about multiple objects in array. It'll work for the current input

Comment: What is the use of Array if we dont have multiple objects? He has mentioned it in the question as "Array Objects"

Comment: The question is markedly under-specified. What do you want to happen with multiple objects in each array? What about objects with overlapping property names? The duplicate covers the basic operation, merging objects.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ismailhossainraju/bLwgeu80/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution using `Object.assign`.

```js
var b = [{"cat_id":"1","cat_name":"teaching"}], a = [{"username":"r","password":"r"}],
    res2 = [Object.assign({}, ...a.concat(b))];
  
    console.log(res2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.assign()` with spread syntax.

```js
var b = [{"cat_id": "1","cat_name": "teaching"}];
var a = [{"username": "r","password": "r"}];

var result = [Object.assign({}, ...a, ...b)]
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extend function to merge objects

```
$.extend( a, b);
```